# Is any extended logging available for cron jobs?

Tags: logs, cron

I have 3 scripts under `/etc/cron.daily`.
My cron logs are written in `/var/log/cron`. The below is an entry for the above cron that has run.

```
(root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Here the `stdout` or `stderr` of the scripts inside the cron is unavailable, it shows that `run-parts` command has run over this folder.

Is there any tricks that can help to log what happened while the 3 scripts were executed?

NOTE: I cannot edit the scripts in `cron.daily` to redirect outs and errs to a log file.

Comment: Output from cron-jobs are mailed to respective job owner. Nothing prevents you from running each individual job in `/etc/cron.daily` with `bash -x`, for example, to see what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix the mail system is the means by which system notifications get delivered to users. You can think of it as sort of like on Windows where something will show in your taskbar with a popup message if it needs to notify you of something. Since cronjobs (theoretically) shouldn't produce any output (since no one should be there to see it) any output (stdout or stderr) is treated as if it's a possible indication of an error or issue and so an email is sent to the cronjob's owner to prompt them to check it out.

So, all output (stdout and stderr) is sent through the local mail system to the cronjob's owner. If the owner is a non-personal account you can direct the local MTA to relay to a real email account by setting up an alias. For example, I added to `/etc/aliases`:

```
root: joel.davis@xxx.com
```

Then ran the `newaliases` command (to rebuild mail aliases database). After that, I started to receive root's email's in my corporate email's inbox:

```
root@xxxxxxvlp05 ~ $ echo "the game" | mutt root -s "No Diggity"
sendmail: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
sendmail: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
```

[image: Look at it in all its glory]

So that's the more or less normal way (letting the system send notification emails). There are other means of dealing with the notification. A few alternatives:

Modifying aliases to save the emails to a particular file:

```
root: /var/log/rootMails
```

Piping the mail to a script:

```
root: |/usr/local/bin/filterMail
```

An alternative to messing with aliases is to use the `MAILTO=` option inside the user's crontab that many cron daemons support. This might be preferable if you only want to receive a particular set of the user's notifications, and not anything that will get dropped into their mailbox (which is what `aliases` accomplishes).

I'm sure there are plenty of others, but you probably want to do the first or last ones, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can run cron with the `-s` option to use syslog instead of sending mails. This works in at least RHEL and its derivatives, FreeBSD and MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do logging yourself inside a bash script:

```
logfile=/var/log/mine/whatever.log

log () {
    timestamp=$(date +'%F %T')
    echo -e "$timestamp $1" >> $logfile
    shift
    for a; do
        echo -ne "$a" >> $logfile
    done
}    

log "Hello world.\nAnd so on..."

[...]
```

If you are running commands that have output you want to log:

```
somecommand 2>&1 >> $logfile
```

You can also send messages and errors to the system logger (see `man logger`) and potentially sort them via the syslog configuration.